# React componentWillMount() called after componentWillUpdate()?

Tags: reactjs

I am in the process of trying to debug a third-party component. What I see happening is that it expects to initialise an internal attribute in `componentWillMount()` and then make use of it in `componentWillUpdate()`. The React [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) says this about 'update' methods:

> An update can be caused by changes to props or state. These methods are 
>   called when a component is being re-rendered

That being said, should the code handle the possibility that `componentWillUpdate()` will be called before `componentWillMount()` or should I be digging to see what seems to be apparent cause of the inverted sequence?

We are using React 15.0.1

Comment: A component shouldn't be able to update before it is mounted.

Comment: here is the problem, component will mount will fire before mounting but your component will be rendered, possible multiple times, before is mounted, render and mounting are not the same, ie your component is inside of a container that is `display: none`. every time the property changes the component will be rendered but does not mean it will be mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned `componentWillUpdate()` will be called only when a component is being **re-rendered**. And `componentWillMount()` will be called right before the **initial render** (a component is mounted just once in its lifecycle). So there are no possibility `componentWillMount()` is called after `componentWillUpdate()`.